AttributeError np.bool, while importing pandas in jupyte notebook on windows. Conda ver = 4.14.0 and python = 3.8.3
I get the following error when I try to import pandas
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool'.
np.bool was a deprecated alias for the builtin bool. To avoid this error in existing code, use bool by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use np.bool_ here.
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
Tried installing numpy 1.19.5 still the same error.

"Tried installing numpy 1.19.5 still the same error." Did you restart Jupyter after installing? Jupyter does not reload packages that are already loaded.

Can you tell what version pandas is?  Pandas 2.0 has no problems with numpy 2.24.
